# Unable to select the city name from the website (goibibo.com)

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a newbie in selenium. I'm trying to automate the website goibibo.com and in the website i tried to enter the city name in the "From" textbox as "Chennai" using the xpath and it is showing some recommendations. From that recommendations i want to select "Chennai".

using Selenium Java 3.141.59, Java SE 1.8. I tried using selenium Keys library. In which as i entered the from as "Chennai" I'm trying to click the down arrow and then click the enter key. (I tried this doing manually and it worked. So i tired to do it with selenium keys library which provides me to do keyboard actions.) [Image of the website and the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw3uL.png)

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc")).sendKeys("Chennai");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ENTER));
```

I'm expecting the code to enter the text chennai and in the dropdown it should go to the first one and click enter. So that i will get the required Source station in the "From" text box. The code is not showing any error. It is entering the value as Chennai and that it. Its not doing any action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time out of 1 second was not sufficient. Try the below code which avoids the implicit wait.

```
 driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();

 driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc")).sendKeys("Chennai");
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("react-autosuggest- 
 1")));

 driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
 driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```